# How can I have custom Finder Icons for NFS Volumes (like SMB icons)?

Tags: macos, icon, smb, ventura, nfs

I have a few NAS/UNRAID servers that I connected to from my macOS (Ventura) client over SMB, but I'm currently swapping over to NFS. From the command line, things are fine and work as expected.

However, on my Desktop, the custom icons I had for the shares/volumes are gone (replaced with the default), and I can't seem to put them back using the technique outlined [here](https://www.macworld.com/article/234925/how-to-change-storage-device-icon-in-macos.html), for example.

I've tried ICNS & PNG files, and these worked just fine with SMB (and still do).

Are custom Volume icons not supported for NFS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Ventura installed, but these instructions seem to work on my version of macOS (High Sierra):

[Change icons for files or folders on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-icons-for-files-or-folders-on-mac-mchlp2313/mac)

Which is also given as the answer to the following questions:

- [How can I change the icon of Recent Folder that I drag to dock on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363623/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-recent-folder-that-i-drag-to-dock-on-mac)
- [How to change the recent files smart folder icon in the dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378816/how-to-change-the-recent-files-smart-folder-icon-in-the-dock)

This would probably make your question a duplicate.

The instructions posted in you [link](https://www.macworld.com/article/234925/how-to-change-storage-device-icon-in-macos.html) do not seem to work well and might be outdated.

Comment: Hi, I'm not asking "how" to change the icon (which I would agree is a duplicate), but rather "why" doesn't it work with NFS?  I'm doing what your links (and the one I've provided in the question) suggest. It works with SMB, but not NFS.

Comment: I did not see where your link explained the use the Preview application to create an `.icns` file. I assumed your `.icns` files are not compatible with Ventura and new ones needed to be created.